# Would an Antimagic Field block telepathic communication with a familiar?

Tags: dnd-5e, familiars, antimagic-field, telepathy

Ichabod the Inscrutable has an imp familiar and is exploring a dungeon. He comes across a series of trapped rooms that have Antimagic Fields in them, and he wants to send his familiar in to do some exploring.The Antimagic Fields completely fill each room, but do not extend beyond their walls.

Ichabod is currently standing outside of the first room.

**Would an Antimagic Field block telepathic communication with a familiar?**

Answer (score 4):

### Yes

A PC’s familiar would vanish as it attempted to enter an anti-magic field, thereby blocking any communication between Ichabod and the Imp.

> [Antimagic field](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/antimagic-field); This area is divorced from the magical energy that suffuses the
> multiverse. Within the Sphere, Spells can't be cast, summoned
> creatures disappear, and even Magic Items become mundane...

> Spells and other magical Effects, except those created by an artifact or a deity, are suppressed in the Sphere and can't protrude into it. PHB. 210

Since the Imp is summoned by Ichabod via magic; ([Find Familiar](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/find-familiar) spell) the anti-magic field will cause the Imp to disappear.

---

There is an unusual case with the variant familiar rules [intended for NPC’s.](https://twitter.com/JeremyECrawford/status/920714594334654465?s=20)

These Imp familiars are acquired by contract and are not summoned via magic.

> **Familiar.** The imp can enter into a contract to serve another creature as a familiar, forming a telepathic bond with its wi lling master.
> While the two are bonded, the master can sense what the imp senses as
> long as they are within l mile of each other. MM. 69

Although an Imp under contract will not disappear entering an anti-magic field, their telepathy may cease to function.

The monsters manual advises that telepathy is a magical ability, as such, telepathy should be suppressed by anti-magic.

> **Telepathy** Telepathy is a magical ability that allows a monster to communicate
> mentally with another creature within a specified range. MM. 10

Comment: this is by itself not a bad answer, but I think it would be improved if you answered the question irrespective of the specific situation - i.e. could a familiar communicate with their master if *the master* was in an antimagic field, but the familiar is not.

Comment: I see, i will add to the answer in a few minutes.

Comment: Note; pact of chain warlocks summon their familiars via Find Familiar.